# Virtual box on 64 bit windows operating system

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I installed virtual box on my 64 bit windows 7 operating system. Now i am planning to install redhat 64 bit on my virtual box , however my virtual box is not listing any 64 bit operating systems during the setup.

Answer (score 4):

From [VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests):

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see Section 10.3, “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).
> 2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

Check if you have hardware virtualization enabled in BIOS/UEFI.